# Suppose a web-server has a threshold to serve 10 requests, what shall happen when it receives the 11th request

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, system-design

I recently came across a system design question which asks --> What happens when a server with threshold of 10 request receives the 11th requests? Since i have very little knowledge , i would need some help.

Some queries in my mind regarding the design --> shall we use message queues? or may be a load balance with messaging queues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Requests should be throttled and limited before they are handled by the Web server, in order to limit DOS and DDOS attacks effectiveness.

The usual design is

Client -> Content Delivery Network -> Web Application Firewall -> API Gateway -> Load Balancer -> Web Server.

The content delivery network (CDN) can cache responses in order to reduce the load on web servers

The Web application firewall (WAF) has to detect attacks against the system and stop malicious requests from going forward.

The API Gateway detects which requests are allowed and eventually applies authorization policies.

The Load Balancer balances the load of traffic to the Web servers. To increase the capacity of traffic that can be handled Load Balancers and Web servers are implemented with containers and cloud native container orchestration engines like docker and kubernetes. container orchestration engines can easily scale up and down the number of Web servers running basing on the current load of traffic.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. Really helped me learn. One question though How is the additional requests are handled ? can we make of any queue or any other mechanism? I'm still looking for that inputs.

Comment: Queues can be used only for async communications, not for sync communications like REST API. In the latter you can only scale up the infrastructure